# Pulling from Excel Returns Arbitrary Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, database, openpyxl

I attempting to pull data from a long excel file using `openpyxl` but the data is not returning the actual value of the cell but some arbitrary name. Below is my code. The same is happening when I attempt to pull cell values with time.

```
from openpyxl import *
#from writeout import  writer


workbook = load_workbook('30 Sep data (C15).xlsx')

sheet = workbook['All monitors, adjusted final']


EGM = []

monitor1, monitor2, monitor3 = [], [], []
monitor4, monitor5, monitor6 = [], [], []
monitor7, monitor8, monitor9 = [], [], []
monitor10, monitor11, monitor12 = [], [], []
monitor13, monitor14, monitor15 = [], [], []
monitor16, monitor17, monitor18 = [], [], []

temp = []

count = 0

for (cellOne ,cellTwo, cellThree) in zip(sheet['C'], sheet['D'], sheet['E']):
   monitor1.append(cellOne)
   monitor2.append(cellTwo)
   monitor3.append(cellThree)

   count = count + 1
   if count == 607:
      break

monitor1 = monitor1[426:]
monitor2 = monitor2[426:]
monitor3 = monitor3[426:]

print(monitor1)
print(monitor2)
print(monitor3)


for cell in sheet['B']:
   #print(cell.value)
   temp.append(cell.value)
   count = count + 1
   if count == 607:
      break

timetrial = temp[426:]
for cell in sheet['A']:
   print(cell.value)
```

Here is the output:

```
[<Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C427>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C428>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C429>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C430>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C431>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C432>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C433>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C434>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C435>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C436>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C437>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C438>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C439>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C440>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C441>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C442>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C443>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C444>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C445>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C446>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C447>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C448>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C449>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C450>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C451>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C452>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C453>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C454>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C455>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C456>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C457>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C458>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C459>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C460>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C461>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C462>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C463>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C464>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C465>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C466>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C467>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C468>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C469>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C470>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C471>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C472>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C473>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C474>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C475>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C476>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C477>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C478>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C479>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C480>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C481>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C482>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C483>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C484>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C485>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C486>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C487>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C488>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C489>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C490>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C491>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C492>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C493>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C494>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C495>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C496>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C497>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C498>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C499>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C500>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C501>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C502>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C503>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C504>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C505>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C506>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C507>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C508>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C509>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C510>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C511>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C512>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C513>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C514>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C515>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C516>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C517>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C518>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C519>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C520>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C521>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C522>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C523>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C524>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C525>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C526>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C527>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C528>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C529>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C530>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C531>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C532>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C533>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C534>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C535>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C536>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C537>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C538>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C539>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C540>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C541>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C542>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C543>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C544>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C545>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C546>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C547>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C548>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C549>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C550>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C551>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C552>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C553>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C554>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C555>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C556>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C557>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C558>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C559>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C560>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C561>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C562>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C563>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C564>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C565>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C566>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C567>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C568>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C569>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C570>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C571>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C572>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C573>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C574>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C575>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C576>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C577>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C578>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C579>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C580>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C581>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C582>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C583>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C584>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C585>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C586>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C587>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C588>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C589>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C590>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C591>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C592>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C593>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C594>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C595>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C596>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C597>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C598>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C599>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C600>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C601>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C602>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C603>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C604>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C605>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C606>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C607>]
[<Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D427>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D428>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D429>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D430>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D431>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D432>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D433>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D434>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D435>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D436>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D437>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D438>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D439>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D440>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D441>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D442>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D443>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D444>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D445>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D446>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D447>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D448>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D449>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D450>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D451>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D452>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D453>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D454>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D455>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D456>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D457>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D458>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D459>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D460>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D461>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D462>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D463>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D464>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D465>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D466>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D467>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D468>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D469>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D470>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D471>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D472>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D473>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D474>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D475>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D476>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D477>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D478>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D479>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D480>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D481>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D482>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D483>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D484>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D485>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D486>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D487>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D488>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D489>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D490>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D491>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D492>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D493>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D494>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D495>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D496>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D497>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D498>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D499>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D500>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D501>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D502>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D503>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D504>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D505>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D506>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D507>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D508>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D509>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D510>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D511>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D512>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D513>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D514>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D515>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D516>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D517>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D518>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D519>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D520>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D521>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D522>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D523>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D524>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D525>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D526>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D527>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D528>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D529>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D530>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D531>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D532>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D533>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D534>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D535>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D536>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D537>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D538>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D539>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D540>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D541>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D542>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D543>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D544>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D545>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D546>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D547>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D548>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D549>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D550>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D551>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D552>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D553>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D554>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D555>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D556>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D557>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D558>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D559>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D560>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D561>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D562>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D563>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D564>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D565>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D566>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D567>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D568>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D569>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D570>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D571>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D572>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D573>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D574>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D575>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D576>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D577>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D578>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D579>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D580>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D581>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D582>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D583>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D584>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D585>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D586>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D587>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D588>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D589>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D590>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D591>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D592>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D593>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D594>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D595>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D596>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D597>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D598>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D599>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D600>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D601>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D602>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D603>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D604>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D605>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D606>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.D607>]
[<Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E427>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E428>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E429>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E430>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E431>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E432>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E433>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E434>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E435>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E436>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E437>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E438>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E439>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E440>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E441>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E442>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E443>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E444>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E445>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E446>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E447>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E448>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E449>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E450>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E451>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E452>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E453>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E454>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E455>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E456>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E457>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E458>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E459>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E460>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E461>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E462>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E463>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E464>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E465>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E466>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E467>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E468>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E469>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E470>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E471>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E472>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E473>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E474>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E475>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E476>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E477>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E478>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E479>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E480>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E481>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E482>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E483>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E484>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E485>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E486>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E487>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E488>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E489>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E490>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E491>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E492>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E493>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E494>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E495>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E496>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E497>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E498>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E499>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E500>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E501>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E502>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E503>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E504>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E505>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E506>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E507>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E508>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E509>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E510>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E511>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E512>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E513>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E514>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E515>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E516>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E517>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E518>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E519>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E520>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E521>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E522>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E523>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E524>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E525>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E526>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E527>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E528>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E529>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E530>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E531>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E532>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E533>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E534>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E535>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E536>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E537>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E538>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E539>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E540>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E541>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E542>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E543>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E544>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E545>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E546>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E547>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E548>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E549>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E550>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E551>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E552>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E553>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E554>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E555>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E556>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E557>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E558>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E559>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E560>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E561>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E562>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E563>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E564>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E565>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E566>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E567>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E568>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E569>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E570>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E571>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E572>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E573>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E574>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E575>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E576>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E577>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E578>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E579>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E580>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E581>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E582>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E583>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E584>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E585>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E586>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E587>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E588>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E589>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E590>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E591>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E592>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E593>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E594>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E595>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E596>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E597>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E598>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E599>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E600>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E601>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E602>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E603>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E604>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E605>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E606>, <Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.E607>]
Time
=TEXT(X2,"hh:mm:ss")
=TEXT(X3,"hh:mm:ss")
....
....
```

Instead of the expected value which is supposed to be a number why I am I receiving values like `<Cell 'All monitors, adjusted final'.C427>` Note: "All monitors, adjusted final" is the name of the sheet in the excel file."

Picture of what the data looks like:

[image]

Comment: You are storing the cells and not their values. `print(ws.cell)` shows the worksheet name and cell coordinate.

Comment: so how would i fix this? i have tried changing ```data_only = True``` but it still results in the same problem. what should i do to fix this.

Comment: Right, beause you're still looking at cells and not their values. Look at what a row is, that should help.